# Firebase Function throws returned undefined, expected Promise or value

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

My below firebase function throws the error Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value. I am doing a return everywhere and not sure why it still throws this error

I have looked into similar code samples and not sure what point does it throw the error.

```
exports.on_order_updated_update_new_vs_repeat_order = functions.database.ref("/orders/{id}")
    .onUpdate((change, context) => { 
        const newValue = change.after.val();
        const oldValue =   change.before.val()

        //if order is marked delivered then update the data
        if(oldValue.order._orderStatus !== 'Delivered' && newValue.order._orderStatus === 'Delivered'){
            //find the uid of the customer 
            const uid = newValue.customer._uid
            var isOldOrder = false  //to track weather the customer is new or repeat

            var db = admin.database();
            var ref = db.ref('users')
            return ref.child(uid).child('orders').once("value").then(
                (resp) => {
                     const orderKeys = Object.keys(resp.val())

                     if(orderKeys.length > 1)
                        isOldOrder = true //existing orders there so just set it to true
                     var date = new Date()
                     var begDate = findDayBegninning(date)
                     var endDate = findDayEnd(date)

                     var anaRef = db.ref('analytics')
                     return anaRef.child('newVsRepeatOrders').orderByChild("date").startAt(begDate).endAt(endDate).once("value").then(
                         (rp) => {
                             if(rp !== undefined && rp.val() !== null){

                                  const newOldObj = rp.val()
                                  var oldOrderVal = 0
                                  var newOrderVal = 0
                                  if(isOldOrder === true){
                                    oldOrderVal = newOldObj[begDate].oldOrdersCount + 1
                                    newOrderVal = newOldObj[begDate].newOrdersCount
                                  }

                                  return anaRef.child('newVsRepeatOrders/' + begDate).update({"oldOrdersCount": oldOrderVal, "newOrdersCount": newOrderVal}).then(
                                      (resp1) => console.log("updated order count") 
                                  ).catch(
                                      (err) => console.error("error in updating old vs new order count:" + err)
                                  )

                             }else{
                                 console.log("no data found for today so adding first record")
                                 var oldOrderCount = 0
                                 var newOrderCount = 0

                                 if(isOldOrder === true)
                                    oldOrderCount++
                                 else
                                    newOrderCount++

                                 var payload = {
                                     "date" : begDate,
                                     "oldOrdersCount": oldOrderCount,
                                     "newOrdersCount" : newOrderCount
                                 }

                                 return anaRef.child('newVsRepeatOrders/' + begDate).set(payload).then(
                                     (rpp) => console.log("updated newVsRepeatOrders")
                                 ).catch(
                                     (err) => console.error("Error updating newVsRepeatOrders::" + err)
                                 )
                             }
                         }
                     ).catch(
                        (err) => console.error("Could not execute path newVsRepeatOrders for the customer uid:" + uid + " error is:" + err)
                    )
                }
            ).catch(
                (err) => console.error("Could not find orders for the customer uid:" + uid + " error is:" + err)
            )
        }
    }
)
```

Please ignore the text from here. stackoverflow does not let me post saying i only have code and add text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not returning anything from the function in the event that the top level condition is false.  Let me compress your function down so you can see more clearly:

```
exports.on_order_updated_update_new_vs_repeat_order = functions.database.ref("/orders/{id}")
    .onUpdate((change, context) => { 
        const newValue = change.after.val();
        const oldValue = change.before.val()

        //if order is marked delivered then update the data
        if(oldValue.order._orderStatus !== 'Delivered' && newValue.order._orderStatus === 'Delivered'){
            // return some promise...
        }
        // nothing is returned if the above condition was false
    }
)
```

You need to return something in every case.  If your function has no async work to do in case the main condition is false, just `return null`.

As a matter of better style and clarity, you may also wish to chain your promises rather than nesting them.  Nested promises are difficult to read, and linters may complain about that, as they are also prone to error.